# Display a Fragment class in a DialogFragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Hello stackoverflowwers!!

I'd like to add a Fragment into my DialogFragment. This is the code that I currently have:

CustomDialogFragment.java:

```
public static CustomDialogFragment newInstance(String searchType){
        CustomDialogFragment frag = new CustomDialogFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("searchType", searchType);
        frag.setArguments(args);

        Log.d(TAG, "newInstance");

        return frag;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        fm = getFragmentManager();

        final View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dummy_fragment, container);

        layout.findViewById(R.id.dummy_fl);

        final Fragment search = new Search(new Searcher(null, getArguments().getString("searchType")), null, null);
        getDialog().setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.Search));

        onFocusChangeListener = new OnFocusChangeListener(){

            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Focus changed");
                fm.beginTransaction().replace(layout.findViewById(R.id.dummy_fl).getId(), search, search.getTag()).commit();

            }
        };

        onLayoutChangeListener = new OnLayoutChangeListener(){

            @Override
            public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right,
                    int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight,
                    int oldBottom) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Layout changed");
**fm.beginTransaction().add(search, search.getTag()).commit();**

            }


        };

        layout.setOnFocusChangeListener(onFocusChangeListener);

//      for(int i = 0; i < fm.getFragments().size(); i++){
//              Log.d(TAG, String.format("fm.getFragments().get(%d).getView().getRootView().getId())",i) + String.valueOf(fm.getFragments().get(i).getView()));
//              View view = fm.getFragments().get(i).getView(); 
//                          
//              if(view != null){
//                  return view;    
//              }
//          }           
        layout.addOnLayoutChangeListener(onLayoutChangeListener);
        layout.requestFocus();
        return layout;
    }
```

When I run the app, it crashes on the line that is marked with ** ** .

The error it throws at me is that the fragment has already been added, how can I display that fragment?

I've tried multiple 'solutions' to get the fragment shown up in my DialogFragment. The 'solution' above is one of the many. 
This is another one:

CustomDialogFragment.java:

```
public static CustomDialogFragment newInstance(String searchType){
        CustomDialogFragment frag = new CustomDialogFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("searchType", searchType);
        frag.setArguments(args);

        Log.d(TAG, "newInstance");

        return frag;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        fm = getFragmentManager();

        final View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dummy_fragment, container);

        layout.findViewById(R.id.dummy_fl);

        final Fragment search = new Search(new Searcher(null, getArguments().getString("searchType")), null, null);
        getDialog().setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.Search));





I'm only using one of these codes to add or replace the fragments.

fm.beginTransaction().replace(layout.findViewById(R.id.dummy_fl).getId(), search, search.getTag()).commit(); --> This will return an error because the id R.id.dummy_fl isn't found in the fragment Search. Duhhh, it isn't in the Search fragment.   

fm.beginTransaction().add(search, search.getTag()).commit(); --> This gives the error described above





        for(int i = 0; i < fm.getFragments().size(); i++){
                Log.d(TAG, String.format("fm.getFragments().get(%d).getView().getRootView().getId())",i) + String.valueOf(fm.getFragments().get(i).getView()));
                View view = fm.getFragments().get(i).getView(); 

                if(view != null){
                    return view;    
                }
            }           

        layout.requestFocus();
        return null;
    }
```

In the Search.java Fragment I've added a line to the onCreateView() View that outputs a Log when the onCreateView() View is called. Only the 'solution' above shows that log entry (which makes sense, since the first 'solution' doesn't "load" the Fragment)

But the result of the code above, is that the view is null, and the onCreateView() in the CustomDialogFragment returns null, which is causing the fragment to not be displayed.

The main reason to use a fragment is that I use this fragment elsewhere in the app, and the changes need to be "pushed" to both fragment usages. Sooooo, I don't want to edit both Search fragments everytime I need to make an edit.

How can I fix this??

Btw: When I remove the Fragment addition of the CustomDialogFragment, it will show the dummy_layout perfectly, with the dummy_textView that is in there. So the CustomDialogFragment can display things :P

If you've got any questions, let me know!

Thanks in advance,

Tim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are dynamically adding a Fragment as a child Fragment,  you would need to use the ChildFragmentManager

```
      getChildFragmentManager()
               .beginTransaction()
               .add(R.id.fragment_child, mChildFragment, "tag")
               .commit();
```

Comment: What is the R.id.fragment_child? Is that the View in the layout that gets replaced??

Comment: That is the location where the child will be placed.  This may help: http://www.techrepublic.com/article/the-good-the-bad-and-the-ugly-working-with-androids-child-fragment-manager-and-custom-transitions/

Comment: Thanks for the link ;-) So I suppose the Fragment will replace the R.id.fragment_child in the main layout, or am I wrong now??